# Login, any better way?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a login system, and, what I did was this:

- The Person logs in
- The PHP code creates a random validate key and stores in a cookie and into the database, together with person's e-mail.
- Person is redirected to me.php (profile page)
- me.php checks if the person have the 'logid' cookie and validate it by checking the database.

Any better idea to do this without checking the database on avery login-necessary page?

Comment: What is the point of the validate key? It seems like you could just use a normal PHP session variable

Comment: just keep it in a session - that's what they are for. and you should focus more on making the login itself secure - meaning no sql-injection weaknesses and safe hashes

Comment: @JimL I tried to use sessions, but, I don't know why, they didn't work, I was not able to get the sessions values by $var = $_SESSION['sess'];, PHP 7.0.13

Comment: Just store whether they're logged in in the session variable, pressing logout sets it to `false`

Comment: @TheWalkingPlay2500 then that's the issue you should be asking about. Please post a (very) simple reproduction of the issue in a new question and get help to fix the real issue (sessions)

Comment: are you sure you used session_start() on every page? because for everybody else, sessions work fine.

Comment: @JimL ok, thanks, but first I'll try to re-do the code at least another 5 times ;-;

Comment: Why giving -1? Just because I started learning php a short time ago and I can't do some things that I can't find out properly and I'm not a 'english well speaker' (I'm brazilian) don't means that u're able to block me for asking anymore (sad face)

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Your question is getting voted down because it's too broad, there's not much in the way of technical specifics, and you haven't posted the most important thing: **What you've tried**. Don't take it the wrong way, but this question is not a good fit for the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: @tadman thanks for finally anyone says what is wrong, and after read all comments I figured out what is wrong, and now I'm almost killing me for being at this level of stupidity, I just forgot to do 'session_start()' at me.php